# How can I hook up a second light when the first lacks enough power?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I added a light to my shower. I ran wiring from new light to an existing single switch intending to add a second switch, but the existing switch only has one set of wires coming directly from an existing light which has power, so by trying to hook up both lights run very dim. So i believe i am wiring it in series, the light must be in between power source. My question is there anyway to wire second switch without having to run a new line.

Comment: You'll need smart switches to make that work.

Comment: Can you not run from the existing light to the new light?

Comment: If the lights are in series, then the neutral wire of one is actually HOT! If there is an accessible socket, such as for replaceable lamps, this increases shock hazard. Rewire in parallel!!